# Mapping menu key to alt using setxbdmap

Tags: keyboard-layout

On an Asus X551M running Xubuntu 14.04, I would like to set the following keyboard configuration:

**The pair of modifier keys immediately adjacent to the spacebar are mapped to control.  The next closest pair are mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>.**

That is, the bottom row of my keyboard looks like this:

```
[ctrl] [fn] [win] [alt] [    space    ] [alt] [menu] [ctrl]
```

whereas I want it to behave logically like this:

```
[ctrl] [fn] [alt] [ctrl] [    space    ] [ctrl] [alt] [ctrl]
```

(I never use the outermost pair of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys, so their mapping is arbitrary.)

In the past I've done this by manually editing my `xmodmap` file, which never Just Works on the first try.  Further, `xmodmap` locks up when loading config files, which is apparently a known issue. Everything I've read on the subject suggests that `xmodmap` is deprecated and I should use `setxbdmap` instead.

So I first tried:

```
setxbdmap -option altwin:ctrl_alt_win
```

which works almost perfectly.  Now my keyboard is logically:

```
[ctrl] [fn] [alt] [ctrl] [    space    ] [ctrl] [menu] [ctrl]
```

i.e. I just need to map the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key to <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  Is there a way to do this using `setxbdmap`?

I next looked through `/usr/share/X11/xbd/rules/evdev.lst` until I found the line:

```
altwin:menu     Add the standard behavior to Menu key
```

and tried that, but it seems to have made no difference.  There is an option:

```
ctrl:menu_rctrl   Menu as Right Ctrl
```

which is almost what I want except, naturally, that it maps <kbd>Menu</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  So, is there any way to do this with `setxbdmap`?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file `~/.xkb/symbols/local` containing:

```
xkb_symbols "local" {
    key <LWIN> {
        type= "ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
    };
    key <MENU> {
        type= "ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
    };
    key <LALT> {         [       Control_L ] };
    key <RALT> {         [       Control_R ] };
};
```

or

```
xkb_symbols "local" {
    key <LWIN> {
        type= "ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]= [            Alt_L ]
    };
    key <MENU> {
        type= "ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]= [            Alt_R ]
    };
    key <LALT> {         [       Control_L ] };
    key <RALT> {         [       Control_R ] };
};
```

(or something between), depending on which kind of Alt you want. And do each time you start X (e.g. in your `~/.xsession` file if you have one):

```
mkdir -p .xkb/keymap
setxkbmap -print | sed -e '/xkb_symbols/s/"[[:space:]]/+local&/' > $HOME/.xkb/keymap/custom
xkbcomp -w0 -I$HOME/.xkb -R$HOME/.xkb keymap/custom $DISPLAY
```

The second line creates a file `~/.xkb/keymap` with `xkb_symbols { include "...+local" };`, i.e. which includes `~/.xkb/symbols/local` when `xkbcomp` (third line) is used with the `-I$HOME/.xkb` option. You can check this file before running `xkbcomp`.

I've not tried this exactly, but this is based on what I'm doing: https://www.vinc17.net/unix/xkb.html (without the `types` directory).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I made the changes to my `.xsession` and tried both options for `.xkb/symbols/local`, but neither worked.  This might be naive, but how does `setxbdmap` know to look at `.xkb/symbols/local`?

Comment: @PatrickO'Neill I've edited my answer to add explanations after the 3 commands. Note that here the `setxbdmap` line just generates a config file, but the config change itself is done by `xkbcomp`. The reason of these two steps is that here one modifies current settings instead of directly defining a keyboard map from scratch. One could also use a pipe between both, as described in the setxkbmap(1) man page. You can check with `strace` whether the `.xkb/symbols/local` file is read.